# Ошибка обновления модели Entity Framework из базы данных

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

У меня существует на удаленном сервере база данных PostgreSQL. Когда пытаюсь обновить модель из базы данных, появляется ошибка, изображенная на скриншоте. Параметры строки подключения точно корректны, Web.config вроде тоже. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: Ошибка Visual Studio]

**UPD:** Попробовал обновить модель из локальной базы (перенес точную копию), выдаёт ту же самую ошибку.

**UPD2:** Решение для моего случая найдено.

Comment: У вас стоит интеграция postgres и visual studio? Например, [Integration](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/ddex.html)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, и VSIX элемент, и их софт, всё, что они рекомендуют, установлено.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наконец я нашел решение этой проблемы. Я удалил существующие пакеты Npgsql и Npgsql.EntityFramework (для чистой установки новых версий). Далее я установил Npgsql v.3.2.7 и EntityFramework6.Npgsql v.3.1.1. Далее необходимо было удалить "COMPATIBLE=2.2.5.0" из строки подключения и пересобрать проект. После этого стало возможным обновлять модель из базы и проверять корректность текущей модели.